# I don't understand how this javascript/jquery codes executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

The following codes will not work if I remove the first line (alert()), and it's obvious that I don't need it. The form that I bound the events to are generated on the fly with jquery. Please what could be the problem? Thanks.

```
alert("");
$("#search").autocomplete('func.php');
$("#c_name").autocomplete('func.php');

$("#search").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        findItem('search');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: What does not work exactly? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alert is giving the necessary delay for the forms to get loaded, after which binding an event to an element makes sense. Without the alert statement, the code is getting executed before the form elements can actually load. Try using jquery's live() function to bind events to elements that are being dynamically loaded. Here is how to use it : http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 5):

It could be that the alert is providing the delay required for the jQuery to recognise the elements required.

Remove the alert() and add the following around the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... your code here ... })
```

Comment: This ensures the code doesn't get executed until the page has completed loading and all your necessary elements are present in the DOM. You can also use the shorter `$(function () { ... execute stuff )};`

Answer (score 1):

If `$("#search")` is called before the search form is dynamically created, the jQuery query will return 0 objects and cannot bind the events to anything.

The call to `alert()` creates a pause that allows the form to be created before the `$("#search")` query is made. You can confirm this by `alert`ing the results of `$("#search")` with and without the first `alert()`.

You must ensure the search form has been created before trying to bind any events to it. If this is not trivial to to do, you may consider using jQuery 1.5+ [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). Deferred objects can be used to ensure the search form is created before binding events to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap this in $(document).ready  a la:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search").autocomplete('func.php');
  $("#c_name").autocomplete('func.php');

  $("#search").keypress(function(event) {
      if (event.which === 13) {
          findItem('search');
          return false;
      }
  });
});
```